# Read all partitioned parquet files in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I want to load all parquet files that are stored in a folder structure in S3 AWS.

The folder structure is as follows: `S3/bucket_name/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/year=2019/month/day`

What I want is to read all parquet files at once, so I want PySpark to read all data from 2019 for all months and days that are available and then store it in one dataframe (so you get a concatenated/unioned dataframe with all days in 2019).

I am told that these are partitioned files (though I am not sure of this).

Is this possible in PySpark and if so how?

When I try  `spark.read.parquet('S3/bucket_name/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/year=2019')`
it works. However, when I want to take a look at the Spark dataframe using `spark.read.parquet('S3/bucket_name/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/year=2019').show()`

it says:

```
An error occurred while calling o934.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 4 times, 
most recent failure: 
Lost task 0.3 in stage 36.0 (TID 718, executor 7): 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainIntegerDictionary 
at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToBinary(Dictionary.java:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetDictionary.decodeToBinary(ParquetDictionary.java:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.WritableColumnVector.getUTF8String(WritableColumnVector.java:372)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I want to be able to show the dataframe.

Comment: Have you tried `spark.read.parquet('s3://bucket_name/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/year=2019/')`?

Comment: Yes it gave me an error message about a basePath? I don't remember it exactly. Oddly, if I try `spark.read.parquet('s3://bucket_name/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3/year=2019/month=1')` it does take all days of that month. Weird hey?

Comment: Yes I am using EMR. Not a clue about the Java version nor how to find out which one I am using

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the "Partition discovery" part of the documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery

Answer (score 1):

In PySpark, you can do this simply as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
(
  spark.read
  .parquet('S3/bucket_name/folder_1/folder_2/folder_3')
  .filter(col('year') == 2019)
)
```

So you will point the path to the folder where it is partitioned into some subfolders and you apply the partition filter which should take the data only from the given year subfolder.

Comment: `An error occurred while calling o787.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 29.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 29.0` That is the error I get, when I use the `.show()` operator for your code

Comment: @Eren Could you please post in your question the whole error message?

Comment: @Eren It looks a little bit like a data type mismatch. Are you using a schema for reading the data?

Comment: How do I filter for the last 90 days?